# What software can I use for Voice activated hokeys?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, voice, voice-command

So, I would like to have a program that will do certain functions based on given voice commands.

1. The most important is to apply hotkeys, ie... "Start Menu" -> windows key, "Back" -> backspace
2. Running a batch script or program
3. Organization of voice commands based on the foreground application (similar to how wacom pens can be customized per program)
4. Voice to text recognition would be nice, but least important.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Oh yea, I use windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're able to record "Macro's" for speech recognition.

[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wsrmacros/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Create%20an%20%20'Advanced'%20Speech%20Macro&referringTitle=Using%20the%20WSR%20Macros%20Wizard%20tutorial) shows how to create macros.

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fad62198-220c-4717-b044-829ae4f7c125&displaylang=en) is the tool you'll need to do so.

Comment: Windows Speech Recognition Macros extends the speech recognition capabilities in Windows Vista. Users can create powerful macros that are triggered by voice command to interact with applications.

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was available through microsoft.  That looks like it will do what I want, I will test it when I get home (im on XP at work). Thanks! 

There are additional tutorials here, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wsrmacros/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Using%20the%20WSR%20Macros%20Wizard%20tutorial&referringTitle=Home