# Is there a way to have voice assist with direct keyboard commands?

Tags: windows, macros, hotkeys, voice

I’m not looking for a dictation app, unless it also has this feature.  Essentially, I could say something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and it would copy.

A [similar question was asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/101443/what-software-can-i-use-for-voice-activated-hokeys), but unfortunately the answer is now a dead-end.

Comment: That almost seems like an accessibility item. Like voice assist for someone who can’t use a physical keyboard.